# Get a PHP tag in JSON data?

Tags: php, json

I have a jQuery carousel that uses JSON data. My shopping cart gives me little info tags like this:

```
<?php ProductName(); ?>
```

I want to put those PHP info tags in the JSON data, so that the carousel is dynamically generated from my database.

How do I get the tags into the data file?

Answer (score 3):

The best way to do that is to create the JSON data using a PHP script that builds a multidimensional array (which has the same structure as the json you want to output) and JSON encode it:

```
<?php 
// make this reflect your jsons structure
$data = array(
  "your" => array(
    "stuff-a" => "foo", 
    "stuff-b" => ProductName()
  )
);
echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

Then you can use that script as your data source.

Answer (score 0):

Try this http://php.net/json_encode

Comment: Thank you.  I have no idea what to do with that.  Can you be a little more specific?  THANKS!