# Using PHP Function in JSON Data

Tags: php, jquery, json

I use a shopping cart called Avactis.  It returns back to me little "info tags" to use in my front end.  They look like this:

```
<?php ProductSmImage();?>
<?php ProductName();?>
```

I am trying to use the Agile Carousel script with some of my product in it.  I would like to use the small image, the product name, the product alt text and the product link.

The JSON data file looks like this:

```
[{
"content": "<div class='slide_inner'><a class='photo_link' href='#'><img class='photo' src='images/banner_bike.jpg' alt='Bike'></a><a class='caption' href='#'>Sample Carousel Pic Goes Here And The Best Part is that...</a></div>",
"content_button": "<div class='thumb'><img src='images/f2_thumb.jpg' alt='bike is nice'></div><p>Agile Carousel Place Holder</p>"
}]
```

And the script on the front end looks like this:

```
<script>

// Code used for "Flavor 2" example (above)

$.getJSON("agile_carousel/agile_carousel_data.php", function(data) {
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#flavor_2").agile_carousel({

            // required settings

            carousel_data: data,
            carousel_outer_height: 330,
            carousel_height: 230,
            slide_height: 230,
            carousel_outer_width: 480,
            slide_width: 480,

            // end required settings

            transition_type: "fade",
            transition_time: 600,
            timer: 3000,
            continuous_scrolling: true,
            control_set_1: "numbered_buttons,previous_button,
            ... (continues on same line)... pause_button,next_button",
            control_set_2: "content_buttons",
            change_on_hover: "content_buttons"
        });
    });
});
```

So, I want to replace the first href with  and the src of the image to   and so on.

I think this has something to do with JSON encode but I am not a programmer (obviously) and need to know where to write the code to translate the  tags to JSON data and if you could give me a small sample bit of code to follow, I would be forever grateful.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm assuming the trailing "]" is actually in place in the JSON file?

Comment: can you post the code that creates this JSON string ? im guessing you want that modified ? its not easy to understand what you want to do ... in what language you want it doing ...

Comment: ¿How do you get this json? ¿Via php or jquery?

Comment: 1) Yes, the trailing "]" is in place.  This is a snippet of the data that gets filled into json.php and is called into the html page.

Comment: 2) I added the code that pulls the JSON data in my question just now.

Comment: 3) My interface page is PHP.  I am trying to use the AgileCarousel script to pull dynamic product data.  My shopping cart already produces this data as little info tags I can use but the script breaks when I add the info tags directly into the JSON data @ManseUK

Comment: Please do not duplicate questions, but edit the previous one instead. If you are unhappy about existing answers, try to think about how you can edit and improve your question - possible duplicate of [Get a PHP tag in JSON data?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9877058/get-a-php-tag-in-json-data)

Answer (score 0):

some quick dirty way how using php you can do what you ask.

```
<?php

$json = "[{
\"content\": \"<div class='slide_inner'><a class='photo_link' href='#'><img class='photo' src='images/banner_bike.jpg' alt='Bike'></a><a class='caption' href='#'>Sample Carousel Pic Goes Here And The Best Part is that...</a></div>\",
\"content_button\": \"<div class='thumb'><img src='images/f2_thumb.jpg' alt='bike is nice'></div><p>Agile Carousel Place Holder</p>\"
}]";

$data =  json_decode($json);

$content = $data[0]->content;

$src = substr($content, strpos($content, 'src=') + 5);
$src = substr($src, 1, strpos($src, "'")-1);

$content = str_replace("href='#'", "href='$src'", $content);

echo $content;
```